# genvar errors while using it in generating CLA

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, vivado

Code for generating CLA

```
module CLA( A,B,carry_in,sum,carry_out);
parameter DATA_WIDTH = 32;

//ports declaration    
input [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] A,B;
input carry_in;
output [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] sum;
output carry_out; 

//declaring variables for propagate and generate 

wire [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] prop;
wire [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] gen;
// declaring a temporary carry to traverse or use it as a pointer for pointing out final carry
wire [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] temp_carry;

genvar i;
generate
for(i=0; i< DATA_WIDTH-1; i=i+1)
//assume that the temporary carry is tied to carry_in  
                                     
begin: carry_propagarion
assign gen[i]                 = A[i] & B[i];                                                            
assign prop[i]                = A[i] | B[i];                                                            
assign temp_carry[i+1]        = gen[i] | (prop[i] & temp_carry[i]);                                     
end
assign carry_out              = temp_carry[DATA_WIDTH];                                                 
genvar j;
for(j=0; j<DATA_WIDTH-1;j=j+i) 
begin : sum_calculation
assign sum[i] = A[i] ^ B[i] ^ temp_carry[i];
end
endgenerate
endmodule
```

Errors:

```
WARNING: [VRFC 10-3486] invalid context for genvar 'i' [E:/verilog/Combinational/carry Look Ahead adder/carry look ahead.srcs/sources_1/new/CLA.v:40] 
ERROR: [VRFC 10-536] constant expression required [E:/verilog/Combinational/carry Look Ahead adder/carry look ahead.srcs/sources_1/new/CLA.v:38] 
ERROR: [VRFC 10-1757] loop count limit of 500000 exceeded; condition is never false [E:/verilog/Combinational/carry Look Ahead adder/carry look ahead.srcs/sources_1/new/CLA.v:38] 
ERROR: [XSIM 43-3322] Static elaboration of top level Verilog design unit(s) in library work failed.
```

Comment: WARNING: [VRFC 10-3486] invalid context for genvar 'i' [E:/verilog/Combinational/carry Look Ahead adder/carry look ahead.srcs/sources_1/new/CLA.v:40]
ERROR: [VRFC 10-536] constant expression required [E:/verilog/Combinational/carry Look Ahead adder/carry look ahead.srcs/sources_1/new/CLA.v:38]
ERROR: [VRFC 10-1757] loop count limit of 500000 exceeded; condition is never false [E:/verilog/Combinational/carry Look Ahead adder/carry look ahead.srcs/sources_1/new/CLA.v:38]
ERROR: [XSIM 43-3322] Static elaboration of top level Verilog design unit(s) in library work failed.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st warning message points to this line:

```
assign sum[i] = A[i] ^ B[i] ^ temp_carry[i];
```

The index variable is `i`, but that line is inside the `for` loop which iterates over the variable `j`.  Since the 2 `for` loops iterate over the same range of values, you can combine them.  Remove the `for` loop which iterates over the variable `j`.

I also got a compile warning on the `carry_out` assignment line:

> Bit-select or part-select index out of declared bounds.

You can't use `temp_carry[DATA_WIDTH]` because it is out of bounds.  I changed it to `temp_carry[DATA_WIDTH-1]`.

This code compiles without errors or warnings:

```
module CLA( A,B,carry_in,sum,carry_out);
   parameter DATA_WIDTH = 32;

   //ports declaration    
   input [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] A,B;
   input                  carry_in;
   output [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] sum;
   output                  carry_out; 

   //declaring variables for propagate and generate 

   wire [DATA_WIDTH-1:0]   prop;
   wire [DATA_WIDTH-1:0]   gen;
   // declaring a temporary carry to traverse or use it as a pointer for pointing out final carry
   wire [DATA_WIDTH-1:0]   temp_carry;

   genvar i;
   generate
      //assume that the temporary carry is tied to carry_in  
      for(i=0; i< DATA_WIDTH-1; i=i+1) begin: carry_propagarion
           assign gen[i]           = A[i] & B[i];                                                            
           assign prop[i]          = A[i] | B[i];                                                            
           assign temp_carry[i+1]  = gen[i] | (prop[i] & temp_carry[i]);                                     
           assign sum[i]           = A[i] ^ B[i] ^ temp_carry[i];
      end
   endgenerate

   assign carry_out = temp_carry[DATA_WIDTH-1];                                                 
endmodule
```

I also added consistent indentation.